# How to change byte to int? - Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, array

I have searched everywhere, but can you please help me to get this Byte into int, there are alot of examples on the internet, but not for a beginer like me

CODE:

```
int Button[] = {2, 4, 7 };

byte E = sizeof(Button);

int I = (int) E;


void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);

  Serial.print (I); // has to be 3, currently 61


  }


void loop() {

 }
```

I don't know why the byte E doen't convert to a int in int I by using the  (int)E command, what would also be convinient would be to read the amount of elements directly  as an int .
(you might wonder, why I want to do this, it is beacause, I am writing a program with multiple buttons, so I just want to add another pin to the array and not have to change the "I" int( the I int is used for loops))

Comment: I wish I could slap myself a million times, because when I said Serial.print(I); and not println, I saw 61, but it was 6, so I just divided by two!! Can someone please explain this, I am so confused with this, thnx!

Comment: there is no need to declare `E` or `I` . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  you can just use a command line like this  `Serial.println (sizeof(Button)/sizeof(Button[0]));`

Answer (score 2):

The code works correctly. The function `sizeof()` returns the number of bytes in a variable, not the number of elements. Your array is of type `int`, which consists of 2 bytes each. So in sum you get 6 bytes for the whole array.

What you want to do (calculating the number of elements in the array) is to divide the number of bytes in the array by the number of bytes for one element:

```
int I = sizeof(Button)/sizeof(Button[0]);
```

The conversion from `byte` to `int` worked correctly, but you really don't need it. You can calculate things with both types the same way. The only difference is the value range. Since a negative element number doesn't make sense and you surely don't want to define more than 255 buttons, you can choose yourself, what you want to use. Using `byte` would save you one byte of memory.

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof` returns the size in bytes. int is two bytes in 8-bit AVR mcu. an array of 3 ints has 6 bytes.

return type of `sizeof` is `size_t` which in 8-bit AVR is same as unsigned int